# How to pick common properties from two types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create type by selecting only members that are present in both types:

```
interface A {
    X: number;
    Y: number;
}
interface B {
    Y: number;
    Z: number;
}

type C = Common<A, B>; // { Y: number; }
```

Is there built-in utility type, proposition or commonly use pattern to achieve this?

*Note: I was able to write following utility type, but I consider it quite difficult to reason about*

```
type Common<T1, T2> = Omit<T1, keyof Omit<T1, keyof T2>>
```

However, is there something

Answer (score 6):

You may find this easier to read:

```
type C = Pick<A | B, keyof A & keyof B>; // { Y: number; }
```

It picks (`Pick`) common properties (`keyof A & keyof B`) from the sum of A and B (`A | B`).

Comment: Hmm, this could be actually simplified to type `type C = Pick<A, keyof A & keyof B>`, right?

Comment: Or even `Pick<A, keyof (A | B)>` ?